# MySQL datatype with many options

Tags: php, mysql, enums

I'm creating a MySQL table to store user information. If one info would be a user's graduation year, from 1970~2014, what would be the best datatype for this? I want this values to give users options to choose their graduation year when they sign up. 
I was going to use enum like this. `grdYr ENUM('70','71','72', ... '14')`, but [MyAQL maual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) recommends to not use numbers as enum values. Would simply adding a character like this  `grdYr ENUM('s70','s71','s72', ... 's14')` solve the problem?

Also, if I were to add more values later on, like year 15, 16, and so on as students graduate each year, is altering the table each time the only way to get this done? With my knowledge, that seems like the only way but altering a table sounds like something that I shouldn't do.

Help please!

Comment: Many experts recommend against using ENUM. If you want to ensure that the values are in a given set, create a table that lists all the values, and make this a foreign key into that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, You should use multiple tables and foreign keys insead of `ENUM`. You should also store any year in 4 digit format, instead of 2 digits. Because... what if You will need to add year 2070?

Secondly, use `DATETIME` or `DATE` type of columns for dates. Or, use `VARCHAR`, `INT`, `TINYINT` for numbers like Yours (I still would still prefer date types). Do not make table (or even a single column BY ENUM) containing only user's graduation  years. Validate it by Your HTML/PHP code. Make a `<select>` with particular option's and validate by it.

**HTML:**

```
<select>
    <option value="1970">1970</option>
    <option value="1971">1971</option>
    <option value="1972">1972</option>
    ...
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
</select>
```

**PHP:**

```
$arrayWithYears = array();

foreach($i = 1970; $i <= 2014; $i++) {
    $arrayWithYears[] = $i;
}

if(in_array($iSubmittedValue, $arrayWithYears)) {
    // TRUE
} else {
    // FALSE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an `ENUM`. If you are storing numbers use a more appropriate type like `INT`, or at least `VARCHAR` if you absolutely want to preserve leading zeros. If you are storing dates, use one of the date types such as `DATE`. This makes the database schema clearer, since the column type gives a hint as to its intent.

I would also recommend storing the complete 4 digit year instead of 2 digits, since two digit years are ambiguous. **Remember:** working code tends to continue to be used longer than was originally intended. If you want to show 2 digit years to your visitors, then do it, but still store 4 digit years in your database. The extra space won't be an issue unless your table is *massive*. That is a trivial UI issue.

The recommendation against numbers in `ENUM`s is because it is relatively pointless. Adding an "s" to the beginning of each number doesn't make it any less pointless.

The reasonable choice for a column is one that most closely reflects the data it will be holding. That is almost never an `ENUM`.